# Py.Test parametrizing based on parametrized fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I have a class scoped parametrized fixture that gets 3 databases for its params and returns a connection to each one.

Tests in a class uses this fixture to test each DB connection attributes.

Now I have a new class with database tables tests that I want to use the above fixture but to be parametrized on each connection tables.

Any suggestion on the pytest way to implement this? I can't find a way to parametrize based on an already parametrized element.

Thanks

Comment: I will assume, you have db_connect fixture, providing three different connection types and another fixture being `table_name` providing 2 table names. Your test case will have two params, `db_connect` and `table_name` and will run 6 times (combining all connects and table names). Is that correct?

Answer (score 7):

Test classes are used to:

- provide setup and teardown functions for test cases
- share some common values during testing

With `pytest` this is not necessary as setup and teardown can be done on fixture level.

For this reason my solution does not use classes (but it could be probably used with them).

To show, that the (fake) connections are created and then closed watch the output on stdout. The trick is
to use `@pytest.yield_fixture`, which is not using `return` but `yield` to provide the value used in
the parameter injected into test case. Whatever is following first `yield` statement is executed
as teardown code.

## "rectangle" style: M x N test runs by two parametrized fixtures

The first case is natural to `py.test`, where all fixture variants are combined.

As it has M x N test case runs, I call it "rectangle".

My tests are in `tests/test_it.py`:

```
import pytest


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="class", params=["mysql", "pgsql", "firebird"])
def db_connect(request):
    print("\nopening db")
    yield request.param
    print("closing db")


@pytest.fixture(scope="class", params=["user", "groups"])
def table_name(request):
    return request.param


def test_it(db_connect, table_name):
    print("Testing: {} + {}".format(db_connect, table_name))
```

If you need more test cases like `test_it`, just create them with another name.

Running my test case::

```
$ py.test -sv tests
========================================= test session starts =========================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.9 -- py-1.4.30 -- pytest-2.7.2 -- /home/javl/.virtualenvs/stack/bin/python2
rootdir: /home/javl/sandbox/stack/tests, inifile: 
collected 6 items 

tests/test_it.py::test_it[mysql-user] 
opening db
Testing: mysql + user
PASSEDclosing db

tests/test_it.py::test_it[pgsql-user] 
opening db
Testing: pgsql + user
PASSEDclosing db

tests/test_it.py::test_it[pgsql-groups] 
opening db
Testing: pgsql + groups
PASSEDclosing db

tests/test_it.py::test_it[mysql-groups] 
opening db
Testing: mysql + groups
PASSEDclosing db

tests/test_it.py::test_it[firebird-groups] 
opening db
Testing: firebird + groups
PASSEDclosing db

tests/test_it.py::test_it[firebird-user] 
opening db
Testing: firebird + user
PASSEDclosing db


====================================== 6 passed in 0.01 seconds =======================================
```

## "Exploding triangles" from one fixture to N dependent fixtures

The idea is as follows:

- generate couple of `db_connect` fixtures, using parametrize fixture
- for each db_connect generate N variants of `table_name` fixtures
- have `test_it(db_connect, table_name)` being called only by proper combinatins of `db_connect` and
  `table_name`.

**This simply does not work**

The only solutions is to use some sort of scenarios, which explicitly define, which combinations are
correct.

## "Scenarios": indirect parametrization at test function level

Instead of parametrizing fixtures, we have to parametrize test function.

Usually, the parameter value is passed directly to test function as is. If we want a fixture (named
as the parameter name) to take care of creating the value to use, we have to specify the parameter
as `indirect`. If we say `indirect=True`, all parameters will be treated this way, if we provide
list of parameter names, only specified parameters will be passed into fixture and remaining will go
as they are into the test fuction. Here I use explicit list of indirect arguments.

```
import pytest

DBCFG = {"pgsql": "postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/mydatabaser",
         "mysql": "mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo",
         "oracle": "oracle://scott:tiger@127.0.0.1:1521/sidname"
}


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="session")
def db_connect(request):
    connect_name = request.param
    print("\nopening db {connect_name}".format(connect_name=connect_name))
    assert connect_name in DBCFG
    yield DBCFG[connect_name]
    print("\nclosing db {connect_name}".format(connect_name=connect_name))


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def table_name(request):
    return "tabname-by-fixture {request.param}".format(request=request)


scenarios = [
    ("mysql", "myslq-user"),
    ("mysql", "myslq-groups"),
    ("pgsql", "pgsql-user"),
    ("pgsql", "pgsql-groups"),
    ("oracle", "oracle-user"),
    ("oracle", "oracle-groups"),
]
@pytest.mark.parametrize("db_connect,table_name",
                         scenarios,
                         indirect=["db_connect", "table_name"])
def test_it(db_connect, table_name):
    print("Testing: {} + {}".format(db_connect, table_name))
```

Running the test suite:

```
$ py.test -sv tests/test_indirect.py
py.test========================================= test session starts ==================================
=======
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.9, pytest-2.8.7, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1 -- /home/javl/.virtualenvs/stack
/bin/python2
cachedir: tests/.cache
rootdir: /home/javl/sandbox/stack/tests, inifile:
collected 6 items

tests/test_indirect.py::test_it[mysql-myslq-user]
opening db mysql
Testing: mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo + tabname-by-fixture myslq-user
PASSED
closing db mysql

tests/test_indirect.py::test_it[mysql-myslq-groups]
opening db mysql
Testing: mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo + tabname-by-fixture myslq-groups
PASSED
closing db mysql

tests/test_indirect.py::test_it[pgsql-pgsql-user]
opening db pgsql
Testing: postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/mydatabaser + tabname-by-fixture pgsql-user
PASSED
closing db pgsql

tests/test_indirect.py::test_it[pgsql-pgsql-groups]
opening db pgsql
Testing: postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/mydatabaser + tabname-by-fixture pgsql-groups
PASSED
closing db pgsql

tests/test_indirect.py::test_it[oracle-oracle-user]
opening db oracle
Testing: oracle://scott:tiger@127.0.0.1:1521/sidname + tabname-by-fixture oracle-user
PASSED
closing db oracle

tests/test_indirect.py::test_it[oracle-oracle-groups]
opening db oracle
Testing: oracle://scott:tiger@127.0.0.1:1521/sidname + tabname-by-fixture oracle-groups
PASSED
closing db oracle


====================================== 6 passed in 0.01 seconds =======================================
```

we see it works.

Anyway, there is one small issue - the `db_connect` scope "session" is not honored and it is
instantiated and destroyed at function level. This is [known issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/570).

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for the answer, the issue I face is that each database uses different tables, the table_name fixture should run on all tables it finds based on the current db_connect connection, it should be dynamic, is that possible?

Comment: @al1616 OK. This type of test suite design I call "scenarios". It does not combine each variant of each fixture with all variants of other fixtures, but takes care to sync the combination to only intended combinations. I will think of it for your particular case.

Comment: @al1616 answer updated showing solution with parametrized function with indirect creation. Indirect means, the value is not passed as is, but is passed into fixture to create one.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks a lot for this, regarding the scenarios, I'm looking for a way not to define them explicitly but in some way to get them dynamically during the fixture and to parameterize on them... I think it's complicated...

Comment: I mean that the databases are predefined but not the tables... I want to be able to loop over the databases and for each loop on their tables... so the test will run in a sort of a matrix on each DB and on each table...

Comment: @al1616 testing has some phases - collection one (searching for test cases to run) and testing (actually running the test cases). Your requirement requires to scan the databases for available tables, but for this you will need db connection. You shall be able to scan the table names within one test case and then sequentially test them within that function, but I am not aware of how to do that in test function, which would be only for one table per run.