# Act differently in test function depending on parameter of parametrized fixture in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a fixture parametrized as follows:

```
class AClass:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.file_ending = file_path[-4:]

@pytest.fixture(params=['path/to/file1.txt', 'path/to/file2.csv'])
def aclass(request):
    return AClass(request.param)

# parametrize this function in a way that it is run two times
# and has the right file ending
def test_aclass_has_correct_file_ending(aclass):
    # assert the correct file_ending for each instance here
```

How would I go about that?

Since I have several attributes of Aclass that I want to test depending on the instance of AClass, I don't want to add the file ending as another parameter to the aclass fixture to unnecessarily bloat the fixture. I rather want to parametrize the test function.

I tried the following:

1. Return an instance of a "container" class from the fixture with all the information I need, though this does not seem right
2. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542653/py-test-parametrizing-based-on-parametrized-fixture)
3. I couldn't really get an [indirect parametrization](https://pytest.org/latest/example/parametrize.html#apply-indirect-on-particular-arguments) working

Do I need something like [this](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349)?

I have the feeling I am missing the obvious, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you want to parametrize a test function/method, use [`pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions). What exactly do you mean *"depending on parameter of parametrized fixture"*? Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, every parameter of the fixture gets parametrized when i parametrize the test function, so I will get 4 tests instead of 2. I would like to assert that the first instance of aclass (first parameter) has the file_ending '.txt' and the second has '.csv'.

Comment: If you're actually testing the class instantiation, why use a fixture at all?

Comment: I have several different classes in the background and AClass is a façade. And testing each of the class instances seems redundant as most of their attributes will be the same. And later on I would like to test more than just the instantiation

Comment: And that's fine, you can *also* use a fixture to provide an instantiated class, it's just that you don't need one for this test. Please provide a more concrete example so we don't have to discuss this in such vague terms.